# Taking a screenshot of html without dependencies

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

### Problem

I want to be able to save an image of either a div or a page (whichever easiest) without using dependencies.

So I have been browsing around for awhile to find many solutions to this problem, most of them I have found use dependencies such as BrowserShot or something else. I was wondering if there was some way to do this without dependencies other than ImageIntervention to manage the images.

Comment: why dont you just use existing dependencies? it will reduce a lot of your time..

Comment: Yeah I will probably end up doing that in the end but I was wondering if anyone knew where to start in doing something like this from scratch.

Comment: if you want to do it from scratch.. just go through the any dependencies code, then see how they do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use google's speed API for taking screenshots. I originally was trying to avoid this due to not being able to use it for development since that would be hosted locally.

The solution is described pretty well [here](https://blog.praveen.science/generating-screenshots-of-urls-using-googles-secret-magic-api/).